# How do I write a list of dicts in yaml?

Tags: ansible, zerotier

How can I achieve a list of dicts in yaml for Ansible? I'm trying to access an API for ZeroTier and update my network

The [API Documentation](https://docs.zerotier.com/central/v1#operation/updateNetwork) says

> ipAssignmentPools
> Array of objects (IPRange) Nullable
> Range of IP addresses for the auto assign pool

Below is what I want to achieve

```json
{
    "ipAssignmentPools": [
        {
            "ipRangeEnd": "172.17.0.100",
            "ipRangeStart": "172.17.0.1"
        },
        {
            "ipRangeEnd": "172.18.0.254",
            "ipRangeStart": "172.18.0.1"
        }
    ]

}
```

My code:

```yaml
ipAssignmentPools: 
  ipRangeStart:
    - 172.16.0.1
  ipRangeEnd:
    - 172.16.0.254
```

The result

```json
{
    "ipAssignmentPools": {
        "ipRangeEnd": [
            "172.16.0.254"
        ],
        "ipRangeStart": [
            "172.16.0.1"
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I transform my expected json to a yaml structure?

Comment: Since json is yaml, you could have written your list of objects directly as in your first example. If you want to write that in "pure" yaml, well... following a basic tutorial like [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) would have lead you to [the result](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/47d80af432fc68005735feff2b4cb6e6) in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yaml is a superset of json. You can use any json to yaml convertor like https://www.json2yaml.com/

```yaml
---
ipAssignmentPools:
  - ipRangeEnd: 172.17.0.100
    ipRangeStart: 172.17.0.1
  - ipRangeEnd: 172.18.0.254
    ipRangeStart: 172.18.0.1
```

Comment: A clear and helpful answer. I did not know that about json. Thank you